# How do I merge sql queries to get output based on dates

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am using this query to show summary of the services that are done to a vehicle.

```
SELECT services AS [Services], COUNT(t.services) AS Numbers
 FROM transacts t 
where services!='NULL' and services='ALINMENT' or
      services='WASHING' or
      services='LABOUR CHARGE' and
      bno!='0' and rem='1'
GROUP BY t.services
ORDER BY COUNT(t.services) DESC;
```

and this is the output I'm getting:

[image]

which is correct!

but now, I want to show it by dates for eg: yesterday's, last month's etc. so I modified my query like this:

```
SELECT services AS [Services], COUNT(t.services) AS Numbers
FROM transacts t
 where services!='NULL' and services='ALINMENT' or
       services='WASHING' or
       services='LABOUR CHARGE' and bno!='0' and rem='1' and  CONVERT(DATETIME,t.cdate,103)=CONVERT(DATETIME,'07-09-2020',103)
GROUP BY t.services
ORDER BY COUNT(t.services) DESC;
```

and getting the output like this:

[image]

in the above screenshot, only the last row is showing data according to date entered.
So not getting where the problem seems to be. Please help!

here is the output after making modifications:

[image]

and the query:

```
SELECT services AS [Services], COUNT(t.services) AS Numbers
FROM transacts t
 where services!='NULL' and
      (services='ALINMENT' or services='WASHING' or services='LABOUR CHARGE') and
      bno!='0' and rem='1' and  CONVERT(DATETIME,t.cdate,103)=CONVERT(DATETIME,'07-09-2020',103)
 GROUP BY t.services
 ORDER BY COUNT(t.services) DESC;
```

Comment: precedence order of the operators could be having an effect. Try using brackets, i.e. `(services='ALINMENT' or services='WASHING' or services='LABOUR CHARGE')` to ensure these are considered a distinct set of alternatives, and not mixed up with the later conditions. See also https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 . In fact you could actually make it more readable by putting `services IN ('ALINMENT', 'WASHING', 'LABOUR CHARGE')` instead of the multiple ORs. P.S. `ALINMENT` is a mis-spelling, it should be `ALIGNMENT`.

Comment: P.S. Your question is purely about SQL, it has nothing to do with C# or asp.net, so I removed those tags. Don't add tags just because those technologies are part of an application in which you're having a problem - only add them if they relate directly to the specific issue, thanks.

Comment: Numbes is a count of rows that match.  So it looks like your WHERE is removing 199 (200 - 1) rows that contain Labour Charge.  The WHERE is not removing any of the Washing or Alinment.

Comment: What exactly is being shown, compared to what you expected? P.S. Please always use the "edit" button under your question to add code and data to your question itself, rather than putting it in the comments. Also bear in mind it is hard for us to know exactly what the result of your query will be when we can't see any of the source data in the table. Perhaps it would help to use a small data sample which you can show, and then we can see the whole thing end-to-end. Thanks.

Comment: Please re read my comment and note the part about editing your question :-)

Comment: Anyway that output looks ok. Presumably there were no "Alinment" jobs done on that day. What were you expecting to see?

Comment: Okay, I'm really sorry for that dumbness, I got it. Thank you very much for your support @ADyson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause is just messed up.  The logic you seem to want is:

```
select services AS [Services], count(t.services) AS Numbers
from transacts t
where services in ('ALINMENT', 'WASHING', 'LABOUR CHARGE') and
       bno <> '0' and
       rem = '1' and  
       convert(date, t.cdate, 103) = '2020-09-07'
group by t.services
order by count(t.services) desc;
```

You don't seem to understand the precedence rules for `AND` and `OR`.  Until you do, use parentheses in any set of conditions where you are mixing those operators.